# Running http checks over SSL with HAProxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I'm trying to check my application (which runs on SSL) with haproxy. As I read the documentation, my options for health checks are:

- httpchk, which sends an HTTP request to a configurable URL
- ssl-hello-chk, which sends an SSL HELLO to the server, but you can't configure a URL.

It appears these options are mutually incompatible - specifying one does not let you specify another. Is there a way to make an SSL request to a specific URL and check if it's up?

Answer (score 0):

In Haproxy 1.5, it is/will be possible to run httpchk over SSL connections.